# Z-transform - exercise using definition

Tags: z-transform

Stuck on using the definition to get the z-transform on a function.
The function is :
$$f(k) = a^k/k!$$

$$\sum_{k =0}^{\infty}f(k)/z^k =\cdots $$

I don't know how I get to $$e^{a/z}$$

Comment: Try to write the Taylor expansion of $e^x$?

Comment: Haha, can't believe I forgot that... Thanks, got it now :)